# Get shortcuts WITHOUT new static/dynamic shortcuts

Tags: android, shortcut, android-8.0-oreo, android-9.0-pie

I'm retreiving all possible shortcuts from the system like following:

```
val pm = context.getPackageManager()
val shortcutsIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT)
val ril = pm.queryIntentActivities(shortcutsIntent, 0)
// I progress this data and show my users a custom dialog with apps 
// and possible shortcuts and then will start the shortcut setup with ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT intent
```

The problem here is, that on android O or higher, above e.g also returns new static shortcuts - for which an app needs to be the default launcher as far as I know. Can I somehow filter them out?

I have a sidebar like app and only can support normal shortcuts and cannot support newer static/dynamic shortcuts because of the missing permission...

**Example**

Gmail e.g. offers shortcuts to labels - I get this possible shortcut above. But if I start to set up the shortcut like following

```
 val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT)
 i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
 i.component = ComponentName(packageName, activityName)
 startActivityForResult(i, RequestCodes.SHORTCUT_CREATE_REQUEST_CODE)
```

and wait for the result, I do NOT get back an `Intent` with `Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT` (and all the others like `Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON`, ...) in it, but one with `LauncherApps.EXTRA_PIN_ITEM_REQUEST` in it. But this is too late, I would like to remove this shortcut from the list above at all as I know that my app can't launch such a shortcut because of missing permissions...